# How can I split an SVN repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

In our group we have a repository, we would like to move the repository, but in he meantime also we would like to delete some folders and re-indexing the revision(delete all the revision numbers which are related to the deleted folder) Is this possible? If yes How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take the repository offline by stopping either svnserve or Apache.

Then dump the repository content to file using a command like

```
svnadmin dump repos-folder/ > repos-dumpfile
```

After that you can split the dump by filtering out the relevant changes by using the `svndumpfilter` tool. In the example below "my-branch" is the path within the repository that you want to put into a separate repository:

```
svndumpfilter include my-branch --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs < repos-dumpfile > branch-dumpfile
svndumpfilter exclude my-branch --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs < repos-dumpfile > nobranch-dumpfile
```

Then you can create the empty repositories for the filtered dump files and import the dump data:

```
svnadmin create repos-branch-folder
svnadmin load --ignore-uuid repos-branch-folder < branch-dumpfile
svnadmin create repos-nobranch-folder
svnadmin load --ignore-uuid repos-nobranch-folder < nobranch-dumpfile
```

You can find further information in the [Repository Maintenance](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering) section of the excellent Subversion Book.